# Не добавить репозиторий в Maven через IntelliJ Idea

Tags: maven, jetbrains, repository

Пытаюсь добавить данный репозиторий https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-third-party-dependencies/  в Maven, добавить то добавил, но он не хочет скачивать с него(
Пишет ошибка 500.
Но через браузер туда заходит и все ок

Добавлял через файл pom.xml

```
          <repositories>
               <repository>
                   <id>JetBrains</id>
                   <url>https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-third-party-dependencies/</url>
               </repository>
           </repositories>
```

Другие репозитории подключаются, а данный нет(

Пробовал зеркало, подключить, но уже через файл settings.xml
Но все также ловлю Error

[image: Error 500]

Comment: Так, может, покажете, как добавляли?

Comment: Пост обновил)
Может кто может проверить , почему не подключается репозиторий?